# Open a very large data file in MATLAB without opening it fully

Tags: matlab, memory

I have a large MATLAB array stored in my disk. It is too large to be fit into my computer memory. I need to get access to only 1 element at a time called by a function. But each time the function would call different elements. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like you need to use it as a [tall array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html)

Comment: What is the file type and what is the structure of data stored in the file (is it some CSV format or what)

Comment: When you say “open”, it means calling [`fopen()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), which does not *load* the file, it does not read any data. Presumably, you are loading the file, not just opening it. Please post the code you are using to load the file, so we know what you’re doing and what type of file you have.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your MATLAB data is stored in a MAT-file `*.mat`,  you can use the `matfile` function for loading only the necessary portion of the array into memory as needed.

```
m = matfile('large_array.mat','Writable',false);
element_a = m.largeArray(100);  % this get 100-th element
element_b = m.largeArray(500);  % this get 500-th element
```

`largeArray` is a variable that is available in your matfile. You can use the `whos` function to check the variables in your matfile.

Now, assume that you have a text file. you can create the file handle by `fread` and then use the `fseek` function to get to the desired byte location. Alternatively, you can use `fgetl` function to read each line at a time. Caution, this method has a lot of overhead.

Secondly you can use the `tall` function in matlab to read the hard disk data. But to use `tall` you have to first create a `datastore object` in matlab according to your file format such as

```
%For Text files containing column-oriented data, including CSV files
myfile_object = tabularTextDatastore('large_array.csv')

%For Spreadsheet files with a supported Excel format such as .xlsx
myfile_object = spreadsheetDatastore('large_array.xlsx') 

%For HDFS file 
myfile_object = datastore('hdfs:///data/')

%Files with nonstandard file format but it requires a custom file reading function
myfile_object = FileDatastore(%File specific arguments%)
```

Hope that helps